# How do I resolve the following conflict in tablets?

Tags: android, tablet

I have developed an Android application for both handsets and tablets. It has been running in both emulators. While I am running in the tablet emulator the size of widgets are filling the screen. What should I do solve this conflict?

Comment: Could you explain your problem, or you want know common answer?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can make two different layouts for handlet and tablets in `res/layout` (for handlet) and `res/layout-large` (for tablet). Layout file name must be same. More explanation and other methods you can found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better check it in the Developer's website, where you have all the information. Here it is  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving your suggestion to the problem.. But it could not make any impact on emulator screen.

Comment: Thank you for giving your to the problem what i have posted.But It could not make any impact on tablet emulator screen. can you give me any other way to solve this conflict?