# how to resolve the conflict?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve the following conflict in tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623009/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-conflict-in-tablets)

I want to use the android project which I created in both the handset and tablets. I am trying to use it in both the emulators. But the widgets which I have created does not fix to the tablet screens. I am using the Absolute layout in  my XML and I tried using relative layout also.And also i used support screen tag in the android project and created the folder named layout-large in res folder. But I did not succeed.

Is there any thing I want to do other than these. Please help